# Cannot read content of SQLite DB via Room and LiveData

Tags: android, sqlite, mvvm

I am migrating from SQLite to Room and LiveData. So my SQLite DB already exists on the device and has some data in it. This is my code to create the DB:

```
public static OfferingsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), OfferingsDatabase.class, "offerings.db")
                    .createFromFile(new File(context.getDatabasePath("offerings.db").getAbsolutePath()))
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}
```

The instance gets created correctly. In the ViewModel I use:

```
public OfferingsViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    OfferingsDatabase database = OfferingsDatabase.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
    offerings = database.offeringsDao().loadAllOfferings();
}
```

My Dao is:

```
@Dao
public interface OfferingsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME)
    LiveData<List<OfferingEntity>> loadAllOfferings();
}
```

The path to the database is correct and the Entities are defined correctly. However, `loadAllOfferings()` returns an emtpy list although there is data. I can execute SQLite statements directly and it works well. It seems the database is wiped each time it is built. How can I achieve that the existing entries are shown in Room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to remove `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` and implement a migration.